# understanding components of schematic

Tags: schematics

I am trying to understand a part of the schematic for a relay based multiplexer. Basically the relays are triggered by

RESET :continuous signal of 3.5VDC <voltage < 16 VDC holds device in an active state

CLOCK: on the transition from <1.5 V to >3.5V, relays advance on the leading edge of the clock; clock must be a minimum of 5 ms in width

I just want to understand what are the purpose of resistors,capacitor & diodes in this circuit. More specifically R1 & R3.

As far as I understand:

1. R2& R4: pulldown resistors. Making sure that these inputs are not floating? BTW both connected to different pins of the same schmitt trigger  IC.So why are the resistors values different?
2. R1 & R3 in series to limit the current? Not sure about them? Also
   why different values again?
3. C1 & C2 :decoupling capacitors to ensure smooth signal voltage
   levels?
4. D1 & D2: 1.5KE20A transzorbs limiting clock & reset to 16V.This is pretty straightforward i think.

[image]

Comment: R1 & R3 makes the delay needed, "probably" to slow down commands. Have you made a simulation to show it? Will be clear after. Values of components are not really critical.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the "pulse", D1 & D2 are perhaps not needed.

R2 & R4 pull-down resistors to make sure C1 & C2 discharge at the "same" time.

R1 & R3 fix the delays of waves at the output.
[image]

[image]